# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: angularjs

Em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo, estou incluindo os arquivos:

#### app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'app.controllers',
    'app.services'
]
```

---

#### controller.js

```
angular.controller('HomeController', function($scope, HomeService)
{
    // code
})
```

---

#### services.js

```
angular.service('HomeService', function()
{
    // code
})
```

---

#### template.html

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        // scripts
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="HomeController">

        // body

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Quando abro a página me deparo com o erro:

[image: Error: $injector:modulerr]

Pesquisei no `Google` e nas poucas pesquisas que achei onde se tratava do mesmo erro que estou tendo, não consegui uma solução para o mesmo. Alguns falam que está faltando algum módulo ou coisa do tipo, mas como mostrei, está tudo inserido e os nomes estão corretos.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 3):

Se seu código está exatamente como o descrito, você, em nenhum momento, declarou estes módulos **'app.controllers'** e **'app.services'** causando assim o problema na injeção.

Seguindo a linha do seu código, deveria ser mais ou menos assim:

#### app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'app.controllers', 
     'app.services'
]);
```

#### controller.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
      .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        // código aqui
      }]);
```

#### service.js

```
angular.module('app.services')
   .service('HomeService', [function] {
   // código aqui
   });
```

Desta forma, os módulos que você injetou como dependência estão declarados. Você também poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

#### controller.js

```
var appControllers = angular.module('app.controllers');
appControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', [function () {
  // código aqui
}]);
```

Caso você queira adicionar mais controladores / services (utilizam do mesmo principio para declaração):

#### controller.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
      .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        // código aqui
      }])
      .controller('OutroCtrl', [function () {
       // mais código aqui
      }])
;
```

ou desta forma:

```
var appControllers = angular.module('app.controllers');

appControllers.controller('HomerCtrl', [function () {
 //código aqui
}]);

appControllers.controller('OutroCtrl', [function () {
 // mais código aqui
}]);
```

Espero que isto resolva!

Comment: Complementando a resposta: Isso é possivel pois `angular.module` retorna o objeto module onde será aplicado controllers e services

Comment: MAS, você não vai conseguir acessar `app.controllers` se não os tiver registrado antes, vai dar o mesmo erro

Comment: Realmente resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

O conceito da resposta do @Marco Antônio está correto, mas contém alguns erros de compilação, por isso vou por aqui uma forma mais simples de fazer:

Ah, e outra coisa, não precisa anexar os modulos `app.controllers` e `app.services` se você não está criando eles, mas registrando controllers e services direto no modulo principal.

### Just Copy'n' Paste

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('HomeController',function($scope){
    //codigo aqui
});

app.service('HomeService', function(){
    //codigo aqui
});
```